# passing data between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So i'm trying to pass data between two views (first view is tableViewController,when cell is pressed data is send to second view,second view got imageView, when data is send image is shown) using this tutorial [iphonedevsdk](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html).

I'm using same **theAppDataObject** method in my views:

```
- (AppDataObject*) theAppDataObject
{
    id<AppDelegateProtocol> theDelegate = (id<AppDelegateProtocol>) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    AppDataObject* theDataObject;
    theDataObject = (AppDataObject*) theDelegate.theAppDataObject;
    return theDataObject;
}
```

When cell is pressed i'm trying to send data `theAppDataObject.imageString = tempImageString;`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tempImageString = (((championList *) [self.champions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).championImage);

    AppDataObject *theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    NSLog(@"tempIm-g = %@",tempImageString);
    theDataObject.imageString = tempImageString;
    NSLog(@"theAppDataObject.imageString = %@",theDataObject.imageString);

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**NSLog output**:

tempIm-g = Champ_0.jpg

theAppDataObject.imageString = (null)

**SecondViewController (show image)**:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:theDataObject.imageString];
    NSLog(@"temp image = %@",tempImage);
    [choosenChampionImageView setImage:tempImage];
}
```

**NSLog output:**

temp image = (null)

My problem is that theAppDataObject.imageString is always null

---

Possible solutions that i know:

Do not use AppDataObject as generic data container and just save data in appDelegate.

Ex.:

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appdelegate.imageString = tempImageString;
```

But i want to figure out how to use protocols.

What i tried:
Make theDataObject global:

**view1.h**

```
@interface championsListTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSString *tempImageString;

    AppDataObject* theDataObject;
}

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *tempImageString;

@property(strong,nonatomic) AppDataObject* theDataObject;
```

**output** of  NSLog(@"theDataObject is %@",theDataObject); :

theDataObject is (null), how is this possible?

Comment: Did you checked my answer ? `AppDataObject* theDataObject;` is local in your code, that is the issue. Write it in your interface

Comment: Did you removed the local declaration of theDataObject ?

Comment: I'm sure this is retutnin null `theDelegate.theAppDataObject`

Comment: yes it returns null, i know this is a dumb error but i miss the init of theAppDataObject in appDelegate

Comment: ya I know that , that is why I updated my answer. Anyway it's happy to know that your issue is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Check `theAppDataObject`  is null or not.

If it is null then:

Write `AppDataObject* theDataObject;` in your inteface and declare a property as `strong`

If `theDelegate.theAppDataObject` is returning null , allocate that object first.

If it is not null then:

Change this line `theAppDataObject.imageString = tempImageString;`

to

```
theAppDataObject.imageString = [tempImageString retain];
```

If you are using ARC set the property of `imageString` to `strong`.

or Check with this

`theAppDataObject.imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWthString:tempImageString];`

Comment: it's not possible because i'm using ARC

Comment: @anonymous: what is the property of `imageString` ? Is it strong ?

Comment: @anonymous: i've updated the answer check the last option. It'll work

Comment: value of theAppDataObject.imageString is null anyway

Comment: Allocated object also retuns null! it is not possible. You need to check `theAppDataObject` is null or not

Answer (score 1):

In a class if you want to use a protocal you can use like as :

```
  // this the way too declare  a protocal.
  // .h file
 @protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>

 -(void)testMyProtocolMethod:(NSString *)testvalue;

 @end

@interface TestProtocolClass: NSObject
{
   id <TestProtocol> delegate;

}
 @property (nonatomic , assign) id <TestProtocol> delegate;
 /* synthesize in the .m file   of          this      class*/
 @end



 //Now you have to use this protocol in any class where you want to use , Do like as:
 //let us suppose you want to use this protocal method in a class named "DemoProtocal".
 // .h file 
 import "TestProtocol.h"
 @interface DemoProtocal <TestProtocol>{

 }
 @end

//.m file
 #import "DemoProtocal.h"
 @implementation DemoProtocal

- (id)init{

  TestProtocol *test = [[TestProtocol alloc]init];
  test.delegate = self;

 }

-(void)testMyProtocolMethod:(NSString *)testvalue{

  // Do appropriate things.
 }
 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

In any class where you want to set any variable of the "AppDelegate Class", you can try this, this will surely solve your problem.

```
 //Declare a variable from where you want to set the value of the "AppDelegate Class". 
 //in the yourclass.h file.
 AppDelegate/* this is the main class of the Application*/ *appDel;

//and initialize it where you want to use or you can initialize at the init of the class.  

appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

 // Then set the value.
 appDel.imageString = tempImageString;
```

Comment: thank you, but as i already said i know that this is works, it's just i want to figure out how to use protocols