# How can i pass string value from one viewcontroller to another without xib in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, string, uiviewcontroller

How can i pass one string variable from my firstviewcontroller class to secondviewcontroller class? here secondviewcontroller class have only ".m" and ".h" files;
currently in secondviewcontroller ".h" file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *value2;
```

in `secondviewcontroller.m` file i am using

```
NSString *str=value2;
NSLog(@"%@",str);

// it prints a null
```

in  my `firstviewcontroller.m` file am assigning like

```
secondviewcontroller *second=[[secondviewcontroller alloc]init];
second.value2=value1;
```

value1  is declared in firstviewcontroller as string ..please tell me one solution

Comment: Haw you go from first VC to second VC?

Comment: CHECK YOUR VALUE1...is it nil ????

Comment: Did you synthesize the property in the SecondViewController.m

Comment: iPatel :value1 is not nil

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652312/passing-data-between-views and http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to assign your value1 like.

**firstviewcontroller.m**

```
NSString *value1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"my value1"];
```

and then assign `vc.value2 = value1;`

Comment: :let me try  but remember i dnt have .xib for secondview conrtroller

Comment: I am asking about value1 which is inside firstviewcontroller right ? so try this way for value1.

Comment: its not working with that methode

Answer (score 1):

**Generally  logic is :**

> **NOTE :** Data type of both *value1* and *value2* **must** be same.

First put in `secondVC.h` file

```
NSString *value2;
```

give its `@property` and `@synthesize` properly.

In your  `firstVC.m`

```
NSString *value1 = @"this is string"; // in your case check it is, proper or not (i mean  nil/not nill)??
```

and at create Object of `secondVC`

```
secondVC *vc = [[secondVC alloc] init];
vc.value2 = value1;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

and write in `secondVC.m` file

```
NSLog(@"%@",value2);
```

and check out put in **console**.

Comment: @Naveen- then i thinks problem in your value1 otherwise this logic is true :)

Comment: iPatel value 1 is printing yar..i dont knw y value2 is not prinitng

Comment: what is value 1 displed????

Comment: my string,i tried all abouve methode but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason appears here is you have not synthesized the property in second view controller's .m file. Unless you synthesize the property it will not initiate and will be nil. Please post the entire code.

You need to declare a variable for the property and synthesize the property so that it assigns the value to the variable.

Let me know if it is not so.

Comment: i syntheszd ..itnot the problem

Answer (score 0):

synthesized your propery and used it with self. value2.

Hope this will solve your problem.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

ok this is my First View Controller it has xib file

.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController * svc;

@end
```

and second with no xib.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;

    @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController * vc;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString * passValue;


    @end
```

in implementation

first .m is viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    [super viewDidLoad];

    svc=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    svc.vc=self;

    NSString * str= svc.passValue;

    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    svc.passValue =[@"StringFromFirstView" mutableCopy];

    [svc viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

and in Second .m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        passValue = @"mySValue";
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"passValue %@",passValue);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and when i Run the code

```
    2013-03-16 13:11:40.178 ali[787:c07] viewDidLoad
2013-03-16 13:11:40.179 ali[787:c07] mySValue
2013-03-16 13:11:40.180 ali[787:c07] passValue StringFromFirstView
```