# Maintaining information between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am pretty new to stackoverflow so please let me know if there's anything I should add or leave out in my posts from now on.

problem:

I have one original view controller that has a tableview on it with 2 options, "Date" and "hairstyle" the user is able to click on one of these table cells and it brings them to a new view controller where they can select a hairstyle/date. When they click done, they're chosen date/style reflects on the original view controller. The problem is, that it won't reflect both choices at once. Whenever you try to reflect one, the information from the other is reset for some reason.

Feel free to let me know if there is any more information you would like me to share in this post. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your detail view controllers are about to pop back to the original view controller you can send the data using prepareForSegue.

In order to give you more detailed info we need more details about how you are doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Eagle11 is right you need to use `prepareForSegue`, before jumping to code you better check this very useful(for me) links:

- [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
- [iphonedevsdk](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html) (my personal favourite)
- [Storyboard tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)
- [Passing Data Between VC](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/)

Some issues:

- [passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652312/passing-data-between-views)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check these out